# How to compare two datetime to find time difference in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two columns

```
Column A:                 Column B: 
2017-08-24 14:01:00.000   2017-08-26 10:12:21.760.
```

How would it be possible using `T-SQL` to find the difference between two dates in hours and minutes?

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the results yourself:

```
select cast(s/3600 as varchar(255)) + ':' + right('00' + cast((s % 3600)/60 as char(2))) as hh:mm
from t cross apply
     (values datediff(second, cola, colb)) v(s);
```

The advantage of this approach over using `time` is that it can represent hours greater than 23.

Answer (score 0):

Use `datediff()` function :

```
select dateadd(ss, datediff(ss, cola, colb), 0) as diff
from table t;
```

Comment: ...uh, what's up with `dateadd`, then?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . That turns the result into a date/time so it is expressed as the OP requests.

Answer (score 0):

this is another option, it would give you a decimal as result, not sure what datatype you are looking for as result

```
Declare @dt1 DATETIME = '2017-08-25 00:00:00.000'
Declare @dt2 DATETIME = '2017-08-26 10:12:21.760'
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,@dt1,@dt2)/3600.00
```